# ggplot2 fill and colour mapping legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a sample data frame with four variables and I'm trying to map `h` variable to `fill` and `s` variable to `shape`. Since my `s` variable can take only two values (either 'f' or 'u') I want to use `geom_point` 24 and 21 which can take `fill` and `colour` argument.

```
library(ggplot2)
h <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x <- seq(1:5)
y <- c(1,3,3,5,5)
s <- c(rep('f',3),rep('u',2))
dt <- data.frame(h,x,y,s)
```

Ideally, my `geom_point` would have black outline and coloured `fill`. I can plot this with the below code and it produces this plot:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x=y, y=x)) +  
    geom_point(mapping = aes(fill = factor(h), shape = s), size = 5) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(24, 21))
```

[image: colours controlled by fill]

I cannot get legend to display coloured keys since colour of legend key is mapped to `colour` not to `fill`.

I can have coloured legend keys if I change my `geom_point` to 19 and 17 and map my `h` variable `colour`:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x=y, y=x)) +  
    geom_point(mapping = aes(colour = factor(h), shape = s), size = 5) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(19, 17))
```

[image: colours controlled by colour]

Legend is displayed with coloured keys but black outline on my points on plot is gone.

Is there any way to choose what is mapped on legend key (`fill` or `colour`) if I used both `fill` and `colour` for `geom_point`?

Comment: I don't get what you want. Can you draw your expected output in Paint/Word/PPT and post it here?

Comment: I think the plot images should be switched -- image 2 goes with code block 1?. Anyway, here is a work-around solution: Add `guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=21)))` to the end of code block 1. Then, the fill colors will show up correctly in the fill legend. I think this might be unintended behavior of the legend.

Comment: @ Tung - I wanted to draw coloured circles with black outline and coloured legend keys. Instead of I was getting coloured circles with no outline and coloured legend (first plot) or coloured circles, black outline and black legend (second plot)

Comment: @ bdemarest - I got workaround where I plotted colour first with colour legend add another layer with fill and supressed legend. It worked but I had twice as much as needed object. My plot operates on circa 15k datapoints so it was getting slow.
Your solution worked excellent, thank you very much for help.
Agree, this might be unintended behavior of the legend.

Answer (score 6):

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x=y, y=x)) +  
    geom_point(mapping = aes(fill = factor(h), shape = s), size = 5) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(24, 21)) +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=21)))
```

Above code produces this plot - exactly as I wanted, credits to `bdemarest`

[fill mapped to legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fdl1.png)

[image]