# ggplot2 legend points not coloured correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

My ggplot2 legend is not colouring correctly - it is appearing in all black rather than the colours of my plot.  I have reproduced this error in the `iris` dataset.

```
iris <- iris %>%
    mutate(
        Size = case_when(
            `Sepal.Length` < 5.4 ~ "Small",
            `Sepal.Length` > 5.4 ~ "Big"
        ))


    iris_mapping <- aes_string(
                fill = paste0("`Species`"),
                shape = paste0("`Size`")
            )


    my_plot <- 
        ggplot(iris,
            aes_string(
                x = paste0("`Petal.Length`"),
                y = paste0("`Petal.Width`"))) +
        geom_point(iris_mapping,
            size = 4, alpha = 0.9, color = "black") +
        theme_bw() +
        theme(
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
            legend.text = element_text(family = "mono", face = "bold")) +
        scale_fill_manual(
            values = fgplots::brew_fg_colors(length(unique(iris$Species))),
            name = "Species") +
        scale_shape_manual(name = "Size",
                     values = c(21, 22))+
        xlab("`Petal.Length`") +
        ylab("`Petal.Width`")
```

[image: my_plot]

Does anyone know why this is happening / how I can get the legend colour to match the plot colouring?

Comment: In the fill scale, try adding `guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21))`. The default point used for  the legend is one without a fill parameter.

Comment: what fgplots is?

Comment: Thank you @teunbrand, if you add as an answer I'll mark it as a solution

Comment: This question can be considered a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253547/ggplot2-fill-and-colour-mapping-legend

Comment: I apologise for a possible misunderstanding, if you should have flagged my previous comment to moderator attention. I was simply suggesting to close this question as a duplicate (which you can do!). The idea of linking to duplicates is to increase the visibility of useful posts - ideally in the end similar questions will be linked to one central post. By closing your question (but not deleting it!) you will help increase SO's value in finding a good answer quickly.